# Dynamic Variable name in binding or nested {{}} inside {{}}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm looking into having a dynamically generated binding where binding itself is evaluated/calculated beforehand. Something like:

```
   <span ng-repeat="extra2 in product.extra2">
        <input type="checkbox" checkbox-group />
        <label>{{extra2.extra_0}}</label> //this complete work
        <label>{{extr_price}}</label>   //this not work
   </span>
```

It doesn't work as is.

`ngBind` or `ngBindTemplate` are not useful.

**Controller**

```
$scope.extr_price = 'extra2.extra_0';
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `{{extra2['extr_price']}}`

and in controller:
`$scope['extr_price'] = $scope.extra2['extra_0'];`

Answer (score 0):

Solved this it

```
 controller: $scope['extr_price'] = 'extra_0';

 view : {{extra2[extr_price]}}
```